# How to join select with itself in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to join select with itself in postgresql?

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT  src, dst FROM records
) as t1
JOIN t1 t2
USING(src)
```

UPDATE:

my table doesn't exists already and I create a table with "SELECT" and I want join this selected table with itself.

Comment: Could you please provide source data, table definitions, what your query is giving you and what you're expecting? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Common Table Expressiom:

```
with t1 as
(
    SELECT  src, dst FROM records
) 
SELECT *
FROM t1 JOIN t1 t2
USING(src)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should fix the question.  But one obvious problem is that you cannot re-use a table alias to define another table in the same `from` clause where it is defined.  Hence, I think you want:

```
SELECT r1.src, r1.dst, r2.src, r2.dst
FROM records r1 JOIN
     records r2 
     USING (src);
```

Comment: Thank you. No, I want join a selected table with itself not an exist table.

Comment: @Arshen . . . That is what this query does.